# Facing issue while running Chroma.from_documents() function

Tags: python, openapi, langchain, chromadb

Facing issue while loading the documents into the **chroma db** .
Here is my code. My Chromadb version is **'0.4.18'**

```
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
Chroma.from_documents(texts, embedding_function)
```

Error:

```
 Expected EmbeddingFunction.__call__ to have the following signature: odict_keys(['self', 'input']), got odict_keys(['self', 'args', 'kwargs'])
Please see https://docs.trychroma.com/embeddings for details of the EmbeddingFunction interface.
Please note the recent change to the EmbeddingFunction interface: https://docs.trychroma.com/migration#migration-to-0416---november-7-2023
```

Currently trying this documentation code
[Basic example](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/chroma#basic-example)

Answer (score 2):

you may use my code as ref.

Just for explanation, the latest version of chromadb is looking for input to be either Documents, Images object. You must also name your input param as input.

```
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions
from chromadb import Documents, EmbeddingFunction, Embeddings
class MyEmbeddingFunction(EmbeddingFunction[Documents]):
    def __call__(self, input: Documents) -> Embeddings:
        sentence_transformer_ef = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5")
        embeddings = sentence_transformer_ef(input)
        return embeddings

custom = MyEmbeddingFunction()

nc = client.create_collection(name="sksu",embedding_function=custom)

for idx,value in enumerate(cleaned_text):
  nc.add(documents = value,
    ids = f"id_{idx}")
  
nc_collect = client.get_collection(name="sksu", embedding_function=custom)
results = nc_collect.query(
    query_texts=["sentence does not have skills in it but shows experience"],
    n_results=5
)

results
```